# What does "&!" (ampersand and exclamation) mean in linux shell

Tags: shell

I found that some people run a program in shell like this

```
exe > the.log 2>&1 &!
```

I understand the first part, it redirects stderr to stdout also "&" means runs the program in background, but I don't know what does "&!" mean, what does the exclamation mark mean?

Comment: These sort of features are shell-specific - it's helpful to include [what shell you're using](https://askubuntu.com/q/590899/12220) and tag your question with the specific shell tag, such as [`zsh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zsh).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within `zsh` the command `&!` is a shortcut for `disown`, i.e. the program won't get killed upon exiting the invoking shell.

See [man zshbuiltins](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins)

> **disown [ job ... ]**
> **job ... &|**
> **job ... &!**
>
> Remove the specified jobs from the job table; the shell will no longer report their status, and will not complain if you try to exit an interactive shell with them running or stopped. If no job is specified, disown the current job. If the jobs are currently stopped and the AUTO_CONTINUE option is not set, a warning is printed containing information about how to make them running after they have been disowned. If one of the latter two forms is used, the jobs will automatically be made running, independent of the setting of the AUTO_CONTINUE option.